# regex between characters including end

Tags: c#, regex

This regex below captures the -aaaa and -cccc but not the -eee
How can I do that?

```
keywords = "-aaa bbb -ccc -eee";
MatchCollection wordColNegEnd = Regex.Matches(keywords, @"-(.*?) ");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a "word boundary" `/\b/` instead of a space, which matches the end of the string as well as a word/non-word boundary:

```
Regex.Matches(keywords, @"-(.*?)\b");
```

or, depending on what characters may be in the strings, just use "word characters" `/\w/` to match the pattern:

```
Regex.Matches(keywords, @"-(\w+)");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MatchCollection worldColNegEnd = Regex.Matches(keywords, @"-(.*?)\b"
```

Word boundary is better than space, please give someone else upvotes though, since I brain farted the purpose of it.

Also I don't know why you included a `?` in your original so I left it, but I believe it is not necessary, as `*` matches 0 or more matches.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: I pretty much always write `[^ ]` instead of `.`, so am used to that logic. I fixed it to match other's responses of using `\b`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
MatchCollection wordColNegEnd = Regex.Matches(keywords, @"-(.+?)\b");
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your regex requires a trailing space behind the capturing group. the strings "aaa" and "ccc" have this, but "eee" does not.

Instead of matching *any* characters occurring after a dash, try matching *nonspace* characters:

```
@"-(\S*?)"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
keywords = "-aaa bbb -ccc -eee";
MatchCollection wordColNegEnd = Regex.Matches(keywords, @"-\w+");
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what exactly you are trying to match here.

But if I understood it right, you want to match any alpha string that starts with `-`

Use this RegEx: `-[a-z]+`